# Use Angular observable and http

Tags: angular

I try to learn more about Observable and i use them for get some json data from a url but i have some issue with get method.
also i want to know if there is another solution for this matter.

```
import { Component , ViewChild , AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `<h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <input type="text" #name >
            `,


})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{ 
@ViewChild ('name') input;

constructor(private http: Http){}

ngAfterViewInit(){

    var keyup = Observable.fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement,"keyup")
                          .map((data: any) => data.target.value)
                          .filter(text => text.length >= 3)
                          .distinctUntilChanged()
                          .debounceTime(400)
                          .flatMap(result => {
                             var url = "https://freemusicarchive.org/api/trackSearch?limit=10&q="+result;
                             var res = this.http.get(url).map(data => {data.json()});
                             return res
                          });
    keyup.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
}
```

Comment: it said : Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: You never inject http : Http; into your constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

You do not inject the `http` instance into your constructor and [Angular relies on dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection). Add the following and make sure the main module has the http module registered so you can use them for `DI`. Remove your current `http` variable from the class definition.

```
constructor(private http: Http) {}
```

In your application module make sure you import `HttpModule` from `'@angular/http'`

Comment: I add that but now i got error after add http to my app.module.ts :
Unexpected value 'Http' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: @M.J - Please read the last sentence of my answer.  You have to import the `HttpModule` in your application's module to use the `http` service.

Comment: thanks for your reply, do you know any other way instead of http that i able to get json result from above url?

Comment: @M.J - you could use `jquery` or create an `XMLHttpRequest`. Using the `http` module though is the recommended way to do it. If you following along on the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) example on the Angular site you can copy/paste some of their module code and examples where they make use of the http service.

Comment: yes i used $.getJSON() before but somehow i don't like to use jquery inside angular 4 that's why i asked

Comment: @M.J - see [Tour of Heroes - Http service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) as a good starting point / example.